# Why are non-webkit browsers displaying this image upside down?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, webkit

https://www.go-apc.com/standup/static/uploads/1374772974.38-image.jpg

In both Chrome and Safari, this image is rendered correctly. But in Firefox, Opera (12), and IE, it appears upside down. Here is a screenshot of the image in firefox displaying upside down https://i.stack.imgur.com/y37zL.jpg

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: That image is hosted on a site with untrusted certs.  Combine that with the odd nature of the question and your new-member status and it seems a little fishy.  I'd recommend either re-hosting the image elsewhere or giving a little more information about your problem.  Do you have any screenshots?

Comment: Yes, the cert is unsigned because this site is used internally at my work place only. i understand people's concerns and not wanting to click on it but there is not much I can do about it. Here is a screenshot: http://imgur.com/gL8TuzF  Also I am not a new user member for  1 years, 4 months

Comment: There could be metadata that's being handled by some browsers but not all. Have you looked at the image in an editor? What if you rotate it 180°? Have you recommended all visitors not using chrome should simply invert their monitor for the duration of the stay? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry it took so long to respond, people below 10 rep can't answer their own question until 8 hours after they ask it.

Ok, so after Xcelled194 suggested that it might be a metadata problem, I started looking at the exif and found this:

`Orientation: BottomRight`

Apparently, only webkit browsers know how to handle this correctly and rotate the image the way it should be displayed. To anyone having this problem, I solved it by looking for the Orientation tag with imagemagick and then flipping it based upon the value and then removing that value from the exif.